# GCM Message with Notification does not open Activity

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using **gcm-server** library from https://github.com/google/gcm. My `Message` has data and `Notification`, successfully received in the device, as shown:

[image: Notification screenshot]

Server code (in Scala):

```
val sender = new Sender(API_KEY)
val notification = new Notification.Builder("@drawable/ic_launcher").titleLocKey("app_name").clickAction("com.myapp.NOTIFY_GENERIC").build
val message = new Message.Builder().addData("foo", "bar").notification(notification).build

sender.send(message, group.toList.asJava, 5)
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter android:priority="10"> <-- I also use Localytics -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="com.myapp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".gcm.MessageListener"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".IntroActivity_"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.myapp.NOTIFY_GENERIC" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <!-- http://docs.localytics.com/dev/android.html -->
            <data android:scheme="@string/localytics_intent" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**But tapping the notification only dismisses it without opening the activity.** Sending the `Message` *without* `Notification` (and displaying notification manually in my `.gcm.MessageListener`) works. Where do I do wrong?

**ADDENDUM #1:** My `.gcm.MessageListener`:

```
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    // Matches Message.Builder().addData("message", ...) in the server
    String message = data.getString("message");

    if (message != null) {
        Intent action = new Intent(this, SplashActivity_.class);

        sendNotification(this, message, action, 0);
    }
}
```

**ADDENDUM #2:** The Activity can be opened if it's already being displayed. It will open it *again*, so when you press BACK, you will see the same Activity.

Comment: Please post your code for `MessageListener`. Also, did you write any activity for showing the notification?

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet I updated my question with your request.

Comment: Please post your sendNotification method.

Comment: @YuriyKolbasinskiy It's already there (in Scala).

Comment: @wiradikusuma Not the server code. Post the `sendNotification` method from android code

Comment: Are there any logcat errors indicating what is going wrong when you tap the notification?

Comment: You need to deal with your notification class not gcm, check here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#NotificationResponse for `Preserving Navigation when Starting an Activity`. Basically you need set up a `PendingIntent` that starts a direct entry `Activity`.

Comment: @YuriyKolbasinskiy @bjiang The idea of using `Notification` (of GCM server, in the server) is so I don't need to handle it manually. It doesn't go to my `.gcm.MessageListener`. It's like this: when the app is not in foreground, notification is shown (but doesn't open Activity when tapped). That's the problem I'm having now.